# How to fix malloc error that object probably modified after being freed

Tags: c++

I'm using new(malloc) to malloc a array but there is an error that the object is modified after being freed

```c
void merge(int low, int high)
{
    int *tmp = new int[high-low+1];
    // int *tmp = (int*) malloc (sizeof(int) * (high-low+1));
    int mid = (low + high) / 2;
    int i = low, j = mid + 1, k = low;
    while (i <= mid && j <= high)
    {
        if (A[i] < A[j]) tmp[k++] = A[i++];
        else             tmp[k++] = A[j++];
    }
    while(i <= mid) tmp[k++] = A[i++];
    while(j <= high) tmp[k++] = A[j++];
    for (int t = low; t <= high; t++) A[t] = tmp[t];
    delete[] tmp; 
    // free(tmp);
}
```

malloc: Incorrect checksum for freed object 0x7fb880402ab0: probably modified after being freed.
Corrupt value: 0x300000000
malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

Comment: Don't really know why you return **void** in the function since the function only does algebra operations.

Comment: And what is **A**? I didn't see its definition in your code.

Comment: A is a global variable that need to be sorted, this function is invoked recursively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the error is caused by that in `tmp[k++]` it has exceeded the length of `tmp`.

Comment: No..sorry, I made such a stupid mistake that I assigned `tmp` from `low`, but it supposed to be assigned from 0. It's not related that if `low + high` is odd.

Comment: @Nahuh AHh. sorry about that. I've removed that from my answer.